# how to set permission on each project in asp.net core when use Azure 2020 as Git

Tags: azure-devops, repository, azure-security

we are using multi layer solution in asp.net core. it means in one solution we have some projects and we use Azure dev ops 2020 as local Git repository, the question is how can set permission for each project? I want to grant pull and push request to testUser1 for project A but at same time I don't want this user have access to Project B.

Comment: actually No, We have some solution that include sub project and several engineer works on it, I want to set access on each project and each of them, problem is that solution could build with all sub project.

Answer (score 0):

> how to set permission on each project in asp.net core when use Azure 2020 as Git

I am afraid there is no such permission setting on each project in asp.net core when use Azure 2020 as git.

According to the document [Set Git repository permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/set-git-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops):

> You grant or restrict access to repositories to lock down who can
> contribute to your source code and manage other features. You can set
> permissions across all Git repositories by making changes to the
> top-level Git repositories entry. **Individual repositories inherit
> permissions from the top-level Git Repositories entry**.

We could only set the permission on each repository instead of the each project.

Besides, since project A and project B are in the same asp.net core solution, there should be a certain connection between them. Users can only see one of them instead of all the codes. It will be difficult to understand that the code is only based on the code of one of the projects. If they are independent of each other, you may consider assigning the two projects in different repo to manage separately.